# Why setInterval only works fine at first time?

Tags: javascript

I am trying setInterval in js to write 'is typing' when someone types but it only works fine at first time after that each time takes less time to do the function!

```js
var personTyping = document.getElementById('typingArea');
var isTypingPlace = document.getElementById('isTypingPlace');
personTyping.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
  isTypingPlace.innerHTML = "درحال نوشتن...";
})
personTyping.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    isTypingPlace.innerHTML = null;
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">

<div id="typingArea"><input type="text"></div>
<p id="isTypingPlace"></p>
```

Comment: You are *adding* an new interval whenever a key is pressed. I don't think that's what you want. Note that `setInterval` will call the provided function repeatedly... maybe you are just looking for `setTimeout`.

Comment: Did you want `setTimeout` instead?

Comment: You probably want to `clearInterval` before setting it again (if that's the desired behaviour)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that there is a major problem with the logic. You want to show the result for 1 second and then clear the content. But every `keyup` event, you are creating a new interval which I believe is not the intended behavior. You can use `setTimeout` instead, and can use `clearTimeout` which acts like a debounce effect for 1 sec.

```js
var personTyping = document.getElementById('typingArea');
var isTypingPlace = document.getElementById('isTypingPlace');

let timeoutRef;

personTyping.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
  isTypingPlace.innerHTML = "درحال نوشتن...";
})
personTyping.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  clearTimeout(timeoutRef)
  timeoutRef = setTimeout(() => {

    isTypingPlace.innerHTML = null;
    console.log('Content cleared');

  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<div id="typingArea"><input type="text"></div>
<p id="isTypingPlace"></p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Everytime you create an Interval with `setInterval()` it will keep triggering the callback forever until you delete the interval again. When your event listener gets called you create new intervals which will all continue to trigger. So you should delete old intervals with `clearInterval()` before creating a new one.

```js
var personTyping = document.getElementById('typingArea');
var isTypingPlace = document.getElementById('isTypingPlace');
personTyping.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
  isTypingPlace.innerHTML = "درحال نوشتن...";
})

let interval = null
personTyping.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    isTypingPlace.innerHTML = null;
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">

<div id="typingArea"><input type="text"></div>
<p id="isTypingPlace"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

```js
var personTyping = document.getElementById('typingArea');
var isTypingPlace = document.getElementById('isTypingPlace');
personTyping.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
  isTypingPlace.innerHTML = "درحال نوشتن...";
})
personTyping.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    isTypingPlace.innerHTML = null;
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">

<div id="typingArea"><input type="text"></div>
<p id="isTypingPlace"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your keyup event listener keeps setting the innerHTML to null, every second.
Instead of setInterval you might want to use setTimeout():

```
personTyping.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    isTypingPlace.innerHTML = null;
  }, 1000);
})
```